# Python - Improve Speed on value_counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, dictionary, try-catch

I am wrangling some raw data and wish to count the instances of certain metrics (column 'Stat') in a chain (denominated by a unique identifer 'c' noted in column 'chain_id'), this is saved to a dict then mapped to a new column (not shown below).

I wish however to:

1. Improve the speed for the loop, which I have to ~10 it/s over the 34k rows, from an initial ~3.
2. Improve the structure of the variety of try/except statements, noting that each chain will not always have for example a 'Kick' or 'Mark', etc. in the value_counts() output, so these are required to be 0.

I've searched for other ways on SOF, but none of the existing answer's suit - please ignore the indentation of the for loop, it will not allow me to correct it

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

s = ['Hitout', 'Kick', 'Disposal', 'Centre Clearance', 'Tackle', 'Hitout', 
     'Hitout To Advantage', 'Free Against', 'Contested Possession', 'Free For', 
     'Handball', 'Disposal', 'Effective Disposal', 'Stoppage Clearance', 
     'Uncontested Possession', 'Kick', 'Effective Kick', 'Disposal', 'Effective Disposal', 
     'Mark', 'Uncontested Possession', 'F 50 Mark', 'Mark On Lead', 'Kick', 'Disposal', 
     'Shot At Goal', 'Behind', 'Kick In', 'One Percenter', 'Kick', 'Effective Kick', 
     'Disposal', 'Effective Disposal', 'Rebound 50', 'Spoil', 'One Percenter']

x = ['Hitout', 'RI-1', 'RI-1', 'RI-1', 'RI-1', 'Hitout', 'Hitout', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 
     'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 
     'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'RI-7', 'CA-27', 'CA-27', 
     'CA-27', 'CA-27', 'CA-27', 'CA-27', 'CA-27', 'CA-27', 'CA-27']

df = pd.DataFrame({'chain_id':x,'Stat':s})
            
for c in tqdm(chains):
    if c == 'Hitout':
        chain_count[c] = 0
        hb_count[c] = 0
        ki_count[c] = 0
        m_count[c] = 0
        goal_count[c] = 0
        behind_count[c] = 0
        cp_count[c] = 0
        up_count[c] = 0
        t_count[c] = 0
        chain_time[c] = 0
    else:
        temp = df[df['chain_id']==c]['Stat'].value_counts()
        try:
            chain_count[c] = temp['Disposal']
        except:
            chain_count[c] = 0
        try:
            ki_count[c] = temp['Kick']
        except:
            ki_count[c] = 0
        try:
            hb_count[c] = temp['Handball']
        except:
            hb_count[c] = 0
        try:
            m_count[c] = temp['Mark']
        except:
            m_count[c] = 0
        try:
            goal_count[c] = temp['Goal']
        except:
            goal_count[c] = 0
        try:
            behind_count[c] = temp['Behind']
        except:
            behind_count[c] = 0 
        try:
            cp_count[c] = temp['Contested Possession']
        except:
            cp_count[c] = 0
        try:
            up_count[c] = temp['Uncontested Possession']
        except:
            up_count[c] = 0
        try:
            t_count[c] = temp['Tackle']
        except:
            t_count[c] = 0
        chain_time[c] = time(c)

df['chain_length'] = df['chain_id'].map(chain_count)
df['chain_hb'] = df['chain_id'].map(hb_count)
df['chain_ki'] = df['chain_id'].map(ki_count)
df['chain_m'] = df['chain_id'].map(m_count)
df['chain_goal'] = df['chain_id'].map(goal_count)
df['chain_behind'] = df['chain_id'].map(behind_count)
df['chain_cp'] = df['chain_id'].map(cp_count)
df['chain_up'] = df['chain_id'].map(up_count)
df['chain_t'] = df['chain_id'].map(t_count)
df['chain_time'] = df['chain_id'].map(chain_time)
```

Edited: Included a sample, with output how it currently works below

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you give us a sample dataframe and desired output?

Comment: @wwnde I have updated the above to include a sample of the data and how each dictionary will look when mapped

Comment: S in simple words, what is the relationship between chain_id,Stat,chain_length and chain_b?

Comment: @wwnde 'chain_id' represents a unique chain of possession, 'Stat' is a type of statistic captured in the unique chain, such as a kick, handball, mark. 'chain_length' is the count/frequency of 'disposals' in the 'Stat' column for each unique chain_id, and 'chain_hb' is the frequency of 'handball' in the 'Stat' column for each unique chain id. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a status column which isolates Disposal, Handball and other acts

```
 df['status']=np.select([df['Stat'].eq('Handball'),df['Stat'].eq('Disposal')],['chain_length','chain_hb'],'Notimportant')
```

Find the frequency of occurance of each of the acts

```
s=df.join(df.groupby(['chain_id','Stat']).apply(lambda x: pd.get_dummies(x['status'])).fillna(0)).drop(columns=['status','Notimportant'])
```

Use Transform to sum and cascade the totals

```
 s[['chain_hb','chain_length']]=s.groupby('chain_id')[['chain_hb','chain_length']].transform('sum')
```

**Outcome**

```
 chain_id                   Stat      chain_hb  chain_length
0    Hitout                  Hitout       0.0           0.0
1      RI-1                    Kick       1.0           0.0
2      RI-1                Disposal       1.0           0.0
3      RI-1        Centre Clearance       1.0           0.0
4      RI-1                  Tackle       1.0           0.0
5    Hitout                  Hitout       0.0           0.0
6    Hitout     Hitout To Advantage       0.0           0.0
7      RI-7            Free Against       3.0           1.0
8      RI-7    Contested Possession       3.0           1.0
9      RI-7                Free For       3.0           1.0
10     RI-7                Handball       3.0           1.0
11     RI-7                Disposal       3.0           1.0
12     RI-7      Effective Disposal       3.0           1.0
13     RI-7      Stoppage Clearance       3.0           1.0
14     RI-7  Uncontested Possession       3.0           1.0
15     RI-7                    Kick       3.0           1.0
16     RI-7          Effective Kick       3.0           1.0
17     RI-7                Disposal       3.0           1.0
18     RI-7      Effective Disposal       3.0           1.0
19     RI-7                    Mark       3.0           1.0
20     RI-7  Uncontested Possession       3.0           1.0
21     RI-7               F 50 Mark       3.0           1.0
22     RI-7            Mark On Lead       3.0           1.0
23     RI-7                    Kick       3.0           1.0
24     RI-7                Disposal       3.0           1.0
25     RI-7            Shot At Goal       3.0           1.0
26     RI-7                  Behind       3.0           1.0
27    CA-27                 Kick In       1.0           0.0
28    CA-27           One Percenter       1.0           0.0
29    CA-27                    Kick       1.0           0.0
30    CA-27          Effective Kick       1.0           0.0
31    CA-27                Disposal       1.0           0.0
32    CA-27      Effective Disposal       1.0           0.0
33    CA-27              Rebound 50       1.0           0.0
34    CA-27                   Spoil       1.0           0.0
35    CA-27           One Percenter       1.0           0.0
```